# Getting error: ""import mongoose from "mongoose"; ^^^^^^

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I'm using node.js with  mongoose.
I'm trying to connect user.js file to auth.js.
After I put : const User = require("../models/User") in the code, I'm getting error.

**Auth.js:**

---

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express. Router(); ``
const User = require("../models/User"); // after adding this, error appeared in terminal

router. Get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req. body);
  const user = User(req. body);
  user. save();  
  res. send(req. body);
});
module. exports = router;
```

Below is the User.js file I want to connect to db.js

**User.js:**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    title: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    title: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    title: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    title: Date,
    required: true,
    
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

Below is the json file:

**- Package . json:**

```
{
  "name": "inotebook",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "inotebook- your notebook on cloud",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.1.1"
  },
  
}
```

Below is the error I'm, getting in terminal

**Error: **

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Node.js v20.10.0

I'm trying to connect User.js and auth.js.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import on the backend like this const mongoose = require("mongoose");